# How to achieve this category output using concat or any similar function

Tags: php, sql

I want to achieve this output:

Cat1

-field1

Cat2

-field2

using concatenation or any function.

I have a nested loop the first one will loop an sql query for categories, while the second one will loop trough a query and when a category match is found it will group them accordingly. for now i was able to group it properly but it is limited to only one loop meaning for loops greater than 1, it ends up getting the last category and only displaying that, so i was wondering if there is a way for me to do this.

the code is like this:

```
 $unsize is the size of the array for the number of categories
 $un is the category array
for($x=0;$x<$unsize;$x++)
 {
  foreach(loop in db)
   {
     if($p->category == $un[$x])
      {
         do some really long code.
         summary:
         $a = "<tr><td>$un[$x]</td></tr>";
         $b = "<tr><td>$p->field</td></tr>";
      }
   }
 }
```

tried using this:

```
  $a .= "<tr><td>Dog</td></tr><tr><td>Dogie</td></tr>";

  $a .= "<tr><td>Dog1</td></tr><tr><td>Dogie1</td></tr>";
```

ended up with

cat1

-field1

cat1

-field3

where field1 and field3 belong to cat1

Table has an id,field,sortorder,category.

Comment: Can you post your table structure? You could achieve this via the sql query itself.

Comment: the table contains the category and a field, i tried using group by category before but it did not work out for me since it will only display 1 field per category where i need it to display a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a sql query and group on categories.

```
Select col, col2, col3 FROM table GROUP BY cat ORDER BY cat ASC
```

Comment: i did try that but unfortunately it only displays 1 field per category not all the fields are displayed.